# Transforming Matrix in R

Tags: r, dataframe, matrix, tidyverse, data-transform

I currently face issues transforming the matrix to the format below. How do I achieve this in R in the easiest way? Ideally, I would like to use the second matrix as a data frame. Many thanks in advance!

```
      Estonia Germany Poland
Estonia 0       2       3
Germany 2       0       4
 Poland  3      4       0


Country1      Country2     Weight
Estonia       Estonia        0
Estonia       Germany        2
Estonia       Poland         3
Germany       Estonia        2
...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the matrix is called `mat` you can use :

```
library(tibble)
library(tidyr)

mat %>%
  as.data.frame() %>%
  rownames_to_column('Country1') %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -Country1, names_to = 'Country2', values_to = 'Weight')

#  Country1 Country2 Weight
#  <chr>    <chr>     <int>
#1 Estonia  Estonia       0
#2 Estonia  Germany       2
#3 Estonia  Poland        3
#4 Germany  Estonia       2
#5 Germany  Germany       0
#6 Germany  Poland        4
#7 Poland   Estonia       3
#8 Poland   Germany       4
#9 Poland   Poland        0
```

**data**

```
mat <- structure(c(0L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 0L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 0L), .Dim = c(3L, 
3L), .Dimnames = list(c("Estonia", "Germany", "Poland"), c("Estonia", 
"Germany", "Poland")))
```

Answer (score 2):

Another, non-tidyverse, way:

```
df <- as.data.frame(as.table(mat))
names(df) <- c("Country1", "Country2", "Weight")
df
#   Country1 Country2 Weight
# 1  Estonia  Estonia      0
# 2  Germany  Estonia      2
# 3   Poland  Estonia      3
# 4  Estonia  Germany      2
# 5  Germany  Germany      0
# 6   Poland  Germany      4
# 7  Estonia   Poland      3
# 8  Germany   Poland      4
# 9   Poland   Poland      0
```

Answer (score 1):

We can just use `melt`

```
library(reshape2)
melt(mat)
```

#### data

```
mat <- structure(c(0L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 0L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 0L), .Dim = c(3L, 
3L), .Dimnames = list(c("Estonia", "Germany", "Poland"), c("Estonia", 
"Germany", "Poland")))
```

Answer (score 0):

Another base R option

```
> cbind(expand.grid(dimnames(mat)), Weight = c(mat))
     Var1    Var2 Weight
1 Estonia Estonia      0
2 Germany Estonia      2
3  Poland Estonia      3
4 Estonia Germany      2
5 Germany Germany      0
6  Poland Germany      4
7 Estonia  Poland      3
8 Germany  Poland      4
9  Poland  Poland      0
```